# Powershell/Azure-CLI - User input variable passed into regex string match?

Tags: regex, powershell, azure-cli

I have a script that automates the resizing of a managed OS disk in Azure. Currently, I need to hardcode the name of the VM in the two spots below labeled as "VM NAME HERE" in order for it to work.

I am trying to figure out how I can take the input for $vm and use it to match the regex instead of hardcoding the names.

Is it possible to do this?

```
# Set the required variables with user input
$vm = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the name of the target VM'
$rg = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the name of your Resource Group'
$size = Read-Host -Prompt 'How many GB should the disk be changed to'
$new_snap = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please name the backup snapshot for your OS Disk'

# Locate the OS Disk information based on the name of the VM
$disk_id = (az vm list --query "[].{ name:name, os:storageProfile.osDisk.managedDisk.id }")
$os_disk = $disk_id | Select-String -Pattern '("VM NAME HERE"[_\w\d]+)' | ForEach-Object { 
$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }
$snap = $disk_id | Select-String -Pattern '([\.\/\-\w\d]+"VM NAME HERE"[_\w\d]+)' | ForEach-Object { 
$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }

# Create Snapshot
Write-Output "Creating Snapshot: $new_snap"
az snapshot create --resource-group $rg --name $new_snap --source $snap

# Deallocate Target VM
Write-Output "Deallocating VM: $vm"
az vm deallocate --resource-group $rg --name $vm

# Resize Managed Disk
Write-Output "Updating OS Disk size to $size GB"
az disk update --name $os_disk --resource-group $rg --size-gb $size

# Restart Target VM
Write-Output "Restarting VM: $vm"
az vm start --resource-group $rg --name $vm
```

Comment: Is that you run your Azure CLI script in the powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test, we can directly use the following command to get the the vm os disk id

```
$disk_id = (az vm list --query "[?name == '$vm'].storageProfile.osDisk.managedDisk.id" -o tsv)
```

For more details, please refer to https://www.craigforrester.com/posts/resize-azure-vm-disks-with-azure-cli/.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to remove one of my variables with this suggestion. For the regex I figured out how to properly set a non-capturing group.

For anyone who may find it useful these are the updated lines: 

'az snapshot create --resource-group $rg --name $new_snap --source $disk_id'

'$os_disk = $disk_id | Select-String -Pattern '(?:\/disks\/)([_\w\d]+)' | ForEach-Object { $.Matches.Groups[1].Value }'